# Clarification of the sign of the normal derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider an annular domain $\Omega$ with inner and outer boundary given by $\Gamma_{in}$ and $\Gamma_{out}$. Suppose that
$$\Delta u = 0 \ \text{in}\ \Omega, \qquad u = f > 0 \ \text{on} \ \Gamma_{out}, \quad\text{and}, \quad u = 0\ \text{on}\ \Gamma_{in}.$$
I just want to clear my confusion on the sign of the normal derivative of $u$ on $\Gamma_{in}$. If $\nu_{in}$ denotes the inward normal vector, then $\nabla u \cdot \nu_{in}$ on $\Gamma_{in}$ should be negative, right? But, if I consider the normal derivative $\nabla u \cdot \nu_{out}$ (still) on $\Gamma_{in}$, where $\nu_{out}$ is the unit outward normal vector, the sign is positive? Is this correct?

Comment: I would say so, according to notational conventions I'm used to. But if you're dealing with a particular text, there's no guarantee, so it would be better to check there.

Comment: Thank you @MichałMiśkiewicz for your comment.